# How to correctly initialize a vector of objects in C++?

Tags: c++

I am fairly new to  C++ and am trying to create a vector of an object and initialize its member, but there is this bit that I'm not sure if I'm doing correctly :

```
 vector<Card> cardStorage;
   for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
         Card card;
         
         cardStorage.push_back(card);
     
     }
```

Basically that is a vector of 20 object of class Card, and push_back takes type Card &, which is pass by reference. Thus, I am not sure if doing this will yield a vector of 20 different Card objects, or all 20 members of the vector will point at one object, which is not what I want since I will need to traverse through this vector to manipulate the object data member (I also definitely don't want to create 20 object of class Card and push it into the vector, since that's obviously bad practice).

Comment: There are no pointers in your code, and C++ isn't going to silently introduce some. The 'default' behaviour in C++ is to copy objects, but beginners often seem to have trouble believing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`push_back` on a `vector` makes a *copy* of the passed in argument, if the argument is an l-value (an object with a name). So `cardStorage` is guaranteed to have 20 distinct `Card` objects in it after the loop is executed, because each `Card` is copied into the `vector`.

You could consider using `emplace_back` to avoid unnecessarily copying the `Card`s into the `vector`, but you could also simply do:

```
vector<Card> cardStorage(20);
```

which achieves the same effect as the shown code.

Comment: `push_back` makes a copy for _lvalue_ arguments. _Rvalues_ will be moved (since C++11 and if move is supported, of course). It might be better to use `cardStorage.push_back(std::move(card));` in the OP's case.

Comment: @DanielLangr Added that option, but for OP's case, using the appropriate constructor seems most appropriate.

Comment: `emplace_back` doesn't move the  object, it creates the object only when inserting into the vector.

Comment: Maybe a silly question: is it preferable (in term of memory) to create a vector of pointers (std::vector <Cards*> cardStorage)?

Comment: Depends on the use case; pointers are cheaper than objects, but if the object is small, then it's fine. Also, using pointers correctly can be tricky, so prefer `vector<unique_ptr<Card>>` if you want to not store objects directly.

Comment: @cigien: If the pointers are actually pointing to objects, it's not cheaper. You're still paying for the objects themselves, plus allocator overhead/alignment waste, plus the pointers themselves.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yeah, maybe depends on the case. If you have objects that have to stand alone and you want to put them in a vector/list (e.g., for passing all of them into a callback function) pointers are ok. On the other hand, if you want to create a vector of objects, you should use `emplace_back`. Am I right?

Comment: @Eddymage+: If you need to copy the `vector`, the pointers would be cheaper, but then, you'd need to use `shared_ptr` or risk unmanaged pointers (which are absolute hell). In practice, if you need to pass a `vector` to a function, the cheapest solution is to have the function accept the whole `vector` by (often `const`) reference; if the function is intended to take ownership of the `vector`, you pass it by r-value reference (using `std::move` for named vars), both of which reduce the cost of passing it to a low fixed cost regardless of `vector` size, w/o relying on a `vector` of pointers.

Comment: The primary reason to consider a `vector` of pointers is if the objects being stored are expensive to move around, and moving them around is expected (e.g. you're planning to sort or shuffle the `vector` multiple times). Similarly, if the objects in question must have ownership transferred in and out of the `vector` but don't support move or copy semantics, then pointers are the only way to do it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks for all the explanations: I still have a lot to learn about these topics and you provided a lot of insights.

Answer (score 1):

That's fine. While `push_back` takes a const-reference (or an rvalue-reference in the overload), your vector holds objects of type `Card`. In this case you'll simply copy the temporary.

You could even avoid creating the temporary at all and call `emplace_back()` to create the new objects directly in the `vector` buffer, or if they're all supposed to be default-constructed, use `.resize()` or a constructor that takes the desired size.

Comment: If the size is known and is fixed, he should use `std::array`. Other than that, exactly what I would have done.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is correct. But it may be more effective.
The most efficient way to init a vector in runtime will be the following (since C++17).

```
vector<Card> cardStorage;
// allocates memory for all the objects
cardStorage.reserve(20); 
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    // constructs the object in-place and returns the reference to that object 
    // so that you you can do smth with card
    auto &card = cardStorage.emplace_back(/*Arguments if needed*/); 
}
```